Django is randomly ignoring certain days when I try to bulk_create. How do I solve this? How does this even happen?
How does Django randomly skip days when trying to bulk_create? The dataset is a CSV exported via a third party tool from a MSSQL Server.
Exhibit 1 - Data from my database:

Note the whole 2024-06-13 is missing.
Exhibit 2 - Data dump from my dataframe:

When I look at my pandas dataframe, there was data for 2024-06-13. So reading the CSV and parsing the date works.

At first, I thought the issue was using too much memory to bulk_create so I tried chunking. The problem still remained. But if it was a memory problem, then it wouldn't so cleanly eliminate that day without affecting the other days around it. The session start/stop times correspond with when the shop opens and closes on the 12th and 14th.

It's not the only day that randomly disappeared. There are other days before this as well that have vanished. Also, the last possible import date was 2024-06-24. After that, it won't import any more sessions that exists in my dataframe. I tried both SQLite and Postgres to no avail in case it was a database issue.


This is how it's imported from my dataframe via DjangoORM:
sessions = [Session(**row) for row in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
       
objs = Session.objects.bulk_create(
    sessions, batch_size=900,
    # update_conflicts=True,
    # unique_fields=['session_number'],
    # update_fields=['tax_invoice_number']
)

I removed update_conflicts to allow it to throw an Error if there was conflicting keys, but it didn't.
For reference, just to show that it's in my dataframe when I dump it out to Google Sheets
Does anyone have any idea why some days just don't get written to the database? Using Django 5.0.6
Update
If I imported only that ONE csv file, it ends up working fine. If I iterated through all the files, one per month since 2023-01, committing via bulk_create once per file, then I get the issue.
I doubt it's a pk issue as I allowed bulk_create to throw an error on duplicate pk, but also manually checked to see if the pk from the omitted records were in the system.

Does it work if you create Session objects one by one in for loop?

@PTomasz thanks for the reply! I didn't try that but I did try only that last csv file 2024-06 itself and it worked fine. However, I have to rebuild the database importing since 2023-01 and that's when I have this problem.

Do you use one dataframe for the entire import, or one dataframe per CSV file?

You could also print all dates of sessions to be created to check if it is problem with initializing objects or bulk_create itself print([session.date for session in sessions]) If some dates are missing then problem is not with bulk_create
